# Error al intentar crear apk

Tags: nodejs, apache, cordova, apache-cordova

He seguido este tutorial al pie de la letra: https://youtu.be/i95uZkOSRj4

Pero al momento de usar el comando: cordova build android. Obtengo el error que muestro en la imagen. Me pueden colaborar a solucionarlo?

[image: D]

Answer (score 0):

Okey primero y principal deberias comprobar que tienes instalado y configurado el SDK de Android

https://developer.android.com/studio

Luego asegurarte que el proyecto android está apuntando a la carpeta de ese SDK que te bajaste. desde Project Settings.

Configurar en esa misma pantalla tambien el JDK de Java.